# sorting (ascending & descending) value based on group same date?

Tags: pandas, sorting, group-by

I want to sort value (ascending/descending) value based on group same date. can anyone help how to achieve it?

```
df =

            a   b   c
21-12-30    2   12  21
21-12-30    3   13  22
21-12-30    5   14  23
22-01-30    6   15  24
22-01-30    7   16  25
22-01-30    8   17  26
22-02-28    9   18  27
22-02-28    10  19  28
22-02-28    11  20  29
```

```
desired output = 

            a        b      c
21-12-30    5       14      23
21-12-30    3       13      22
21-12-30    2       12      21
22-01-30    8       17      26
22-01-30    7       16      25
22-01-30    6       15      24
22-02-28    11      20      29
22-02-28    10      19      28
22-02-28    9       18      27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

```
out = (df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False, sort=False)
         .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='a', ascending=False))
      )
```

Another:

```
out = df.sort_values(by='a', ascending=False).sort_index(kind='stable')
```

output:

```
           a   b   c
21-12-30   5  14  23
21-12-30   3  13  22
21-12-30   2  12  21
22-01-30   8  17  26
22-01-30   7  16  25
22-01-30   6  15  24
22-02-28  11  20  29
22-02-28  10  19  28
22-02-28   9  18  27
```

Comment: many thanks mozway.. both options works great.. thanks for your answer. hope can be helpful to the community